# Telethon do something if no messages arrive

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-asyncio, telethon

This code leaves python waiting synchronously for messages.
Is there any way to run a function, every so often when a telethon message is not received?

```
async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())
    @client.on(events.NewMessage('TelegramID'))
    async def new_message_listener(event):
        mensaje = event.message.message
        if mensaje != None:
           print(mensaje)
```

I would like that every 10 minutes that it doesn't receive messages it does something, without stopping waiting to receive new messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the asyncio event loop is running, messages will be received. This means you can do the following and it will still work:

```py
import asyncio  # <- new

async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())
    @client.on(events.NewMessage('TelegramID'))
    async def new_message_listener(event):
        mensaje = event.message.message
        if mensaje != None:
           print(mensaje)

    while client.is_connected():  # <- new
        await asyncio.sleep(10 * 60)
        # do something else every 10 minutes...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Very good clarifications